# Why Date picker clear my input and select after clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in `datepicker`. My form has input and select option. After click input `datepicker`, my input and select always reset to first load page. What is my problem?

```
 $('.myClassDate').datepicker({
           format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
           todayBtn: 'linked',
           todayHighlight : true,
           autoclose: true
         });
```

Comment: have you added jquery UI?

Comment: Please add html code for more understanding with  this no one can help you. please refer for more https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which datepicker plugin you refers to ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe button in your form has not `type="button"` and your page will reload after click button